# Conservation of angular momentum after adding an axis of rotation constraint

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

One of my homework assignments had a two dimensional disc rotating around its center of mass on a floor without friction (the rotation axis is perpendicular to the floor). Then, a new axis of rotation was formed by nailing it to the floor at a certain point (which is not the center of mass). Reading the answer to the assignment, it was said that angular momentum is conserved, and energy is not. I honestly don't get it and would love to have an explanation as to why.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Think of the equations for momentum and kinetic energy. Angular momentum=Rotational inertia(Angular velocity). If momentum is conserved, decreasing rotational inertia would result in an increase of velocity. We then see that KE=1/2(Rotational inertia)(Angular velocity)^2. If we plug our new values into the formula, and compare it to the initial KE, we find that it is four times greater.

Comment: I get that they can't both be conserved in this scenario, but I still can't grasp why it's the angular momentum that is conserved.

Comment: Oh ok I see. Well in this scenario, kinetic energy is not conserved, but that doesn't mean energy in total is not conserved. Other types of energy are at work in the beginning, but they convert to kinetic energy after increasing the velocity. Hopefully I have this right.... If not, I'm really sorry....